# SPIN Hack in GraphDB

Tags: graphdb

I have an ontology that I created in TopBraid that uses SPIN + OWL inference. I've been trying to figure out a way to decouple SPIN because most RDF graph database vendors still do not support the standard.

The approach that I've come up with using GraphDB is to load my ontology into GraphDB and then execute each spin:rule present in my ontology as a SPARQL UPDATE/INSERT.

First thing I'm trying to figure out if I can temporarily turn off the GraphDB reasoner while I make a set of SPARQL INSERTS/UPDATES and then turn on the reasoner thereafter.

Secondly, although likely not recommended, would it be possible for the SPARQL INSERT/UPDATES to be added to the implicit graph and not the explicit graph?

If someone has a better idea on how to do this do let me know.

Comment: They have rules: http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/standard/reasoning.html

Comment: I agree that rules are likely the best way to go, but 1) I don't believe that rules can create new IRIs which I require. 2) I want my rules to be written in some standard's based language. 3) The rules I have are fairly complex, which is why I went down the SPIN route in the first place.

Comment: Well, possibly you could try RDF4J: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=rdf4j+spin+is%3Aq

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can turn off the reasoner by selecting a default ruleset the is empty (or very basic), as explained here http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/free/reasoning.html (Set a default ruleset).

But if you want your SPIN rules, translated to INSERT/UPDATE, to be completely executed you must
1- execute the NSERT/UPDATEs
2- lauch the reasoner
repeat 1 and 2 until no new triple is generated